# How to publish a asp.net 5 project in visual studio 2015 to a docker image or linux without azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

in visual studio 2015 i have a asp.net 5 web application which runs fine on windows. But i like to run it under linux. I already set up a linux vm with centOS 7 and installed the needed resources as described under [installing-on-centos-7](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html#installing-on-centos-7).

Now i like to publish the web application into the linux vm. How can i do this? What i have to do to publish it, any hints?

I already read many sites about using docker with azure but this is not an option (because of company reasons).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `dnx publish` or `dotnet publish` and you'll get the published app. Then copy all the files in docker container or add the copy step to the dockerfile

Comment: Thank you this directed me to the point. I also found some good posts how to get the asp.net site in a docker container running under ubuntu.[ASP.NET 5 Running in Docker on Windows](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/10/25/asp-net-5-running-in-docker-on-windows/) and [Using Docker ENV with ASP.NET 5](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/11/04/using-docker-env-with-asp-net-5/)